# Добавить (действие:Клик) в JavaScript код

Tags: jquery, javascript

[Есть страница](http://test.top-yarus.ru/map3.html). На ней в начале расположены ссылки с якорями на слои расположенные ниже. Также к странице прикреплён скрипт который осуществляет скролл к якорю (слою) указанному в ссылке.
Каждый из этих слоёв к которым осуществляется скролл представляет собой мини эскиз, при нажатии на который увеличивается картинка. Увеличение реализовано при помощи скрипта **highslide**.

**Нужно сделать так**, чтобы всё происходило по следующему сценарию:

Клик по ссылке - Скрол до слоя, а затем увеличение картинки.

Иначе говоря нужно в скрипте скролла прописать, чтобы при достижении нужного якоря происходило нажатие на эскиз. C JavaScript я не знаком, но думаю задача не сложная!

**Код скролл скрипта такой:**

```
spScrollToHash = {
    autor: {
        name: 'Szen',
        site: 'http://szenprogs.ru/',
        page: 'http://szenprogs.ru/blog/plavnyj_skrolling_v_ljubom_napravlenii/2011-06-21-111',
        ver: '1.0 beta'
    },

    scroll: function (id, speed, typ) {
        if (id == '' || id == '#' || $(id).length == 0) return false;
        if (speed == undefined || speed < 1 || speed > 1000) speed = 500;
        if (typ == undefined || typ < 1 || typ > 3) typ = 1;
        var par = 'html'
        if ($.browser.safari) par = 'body';
        var offset = $(id).offset();
        spScrollToHash.stop();
        switch (typ) {
        case 1:
            $(par).animate({
                scrollTop: offset.top,
                scrollLeft: offset.left
            }, speed, function () {
                document.location.hash = id;
            });
            break;
        case 2:
            $(par).animate({
                scrollTop: offset.top
            }, Math.round(speed / 2), function () {
                $(par).animate({
                    scrollLeft: offset.left
                }, Math.round(speed / 2), function () {
                    document.location.hash = id;
                });
            });
            break;
        case 3:
            $(par).animate({
                scrollLeft: offset.left
            }, Math.round(speed / 2), function () {
                $(par).animate({
                    scrollTop: offset.top
                }, Math.round(speed / 2), function () {
                    document.location.hash = id;
                });
            });
            break;
        }
        return false;
    },

    stop: function () {
        $('a[href*="#"]').stop();
    },

    ready: function (speed, typ) {
        var id = document.location.hash;
        spScrollToHash.scroll(id, speed, typ);
        $('a[href*="#"]').click(function () {
            id = $(this).attr('href');
            id = id.substr(id.indexOf('#'));
            spScrollToHash.scroll(id, speed, typ);
            return false;
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    spScrollToHash.ready(400, 1);
});
```

[Еще тут.](http://test.top-yarus.ru/map2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуй заменить swith в scroll на:

```
switch(typ){
    case 1:
      $(par).animate({scrollTop:offset.top,scrollLeft:offset.left},speed,function(){document.location.hash=id;$(id).find('a').click();});
      break;
    case 2:
      $(par).animate({scrollTop:offset.top},Math.round(speed/2),function(){
        $(par).animate({scrollLeft:offset.left},Math.round(speed/2),function(){document.location.hash=id;$(id).find('a').click();});
      });
      break;
    case 3:
      $(par).animate({scrollLeft:offset.left},Math.round(speed/2),function(){
        $(par).animate({scrollTop:offset.top},Math.round(speed/2),function(){document.location.hash=id;$(id).find('a').click();});
      });
      break;
  }
```

Comment: Всё работает отлично, только он привязан к "id=thumb1" и при клике на разные ссылки открывает одну и ту же картинку. А если ссылка будет такого вида  
<a href="img/map/objects/3/3.gif" class="highslide" onclick="return hs.expand(this)"> <img src="img/map/objects/3/3_min.gif" alt="Highslide JS" title="1989г. - жилые кварталы в 14-15-м МКР в Северном жилом р-не (РП)." height="56" width="90" /></a>

Comment: тут будет сложно отследить элемент по которому нужен клик, тк при id есть возможность однозначно отловить элементь, но если привязываться к классу, то тогда нужно из нескольких элементов выбрать нужный

Comment: Как же быть, друг! Помоги пожалуйста, javascript не владею может есть какое нибудь решение?

Comment: тут всё зависит от того что можно менять, может есть где в нете глянуть ваш сайт? просто я не совсем понимаю зачем это нужно, а следовательно не могу и предположить как выглядит dom

Comment: выправил код, по идее вам надо так  
если не прокатит, то после свитча поставь alert(id) и потом отпиши что выведет

Comment: ничего не происходит после изменений, после свитча поставил alert(id) выдаёт #pos1 по второй ссылке #pos2 и т.д.

Comment: по идее сейчас в последний раз подправил, просто думал что id без решётки приходит

Comment: Спасибо Друг! Всё работает как доктор прописал!